# Broken dependencies due to libjackd

Tags: dpkg

So I proudly updated my Linux distro for the first time and thereafter got a problem.
I'm running Ubuntu Unity 2D (usually) 12.04 (since today) on a 64 bit computer.

Indeed, the first upgrade -- I made the upgrade through the Update Manager -- was okay (even if I was surprised by the amount of i386 packages that had to be installed).

Then, I re-enabled the repositories that had been disabled because of the upgrade and updated my system. I was told to perform a 'Partial Upgrade', that I did, but was once again surprised by the amount of i386 packages installed and also by the fact that LMMS (https://launchpad.net/lmms) was being removed; Wine, among others, was also being updated and that's probably the reason because LMMS depends on certain versions of Wine (I just know this, for the rest I'm a total noob). Anyway, this leaded me to the broken dependencies `gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386` and `libasound2-plugins:i386`. Synaptic also constantly tries to install `libjack-jackd2-0:i386`, but each time it gets an error.
I don't know if all this is Wine or LMMS related, but it maybe can help...

I was told to perform: '`sudo apt-get -f install`' by Synaptic but it apparently failed:

```
    ~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libxml++2.6-2 librtaudio4 libx264-116 libfluidsynth1 lmms-common librtmidi1
  wine-gecko1.4 wine-gecko1.4:i386 libffado2 stk libconfig++8 libstk0c2a
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386
Suggested packages:
  jackd2:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/202 kB of archives.
After this operation, 493 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 249517 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libjack-jackd2-0:i386 (from .../libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 './usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/buildinfo.gz' is different from the same file on the system
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Must I remove those broken packages via Synaptic?
I would like to understand that problem as I can't install anything new from the Software Center.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

That's a bug in the `libjack-jackd2-0` package, version `1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1` (which isn't a version ever published in Ubuntu, must have come from somewhere else). It claims to be `Multi-Arch: same`, but that file differs between architectures.

You can almost certainly safely delete `/usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/buildinfo.gz`, after which APT should be happy:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/buildinfo.gz
```

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jackd2/+bug/999665
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just renaming

```
/usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/
```

to

```
/usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0.old
```

and then ran

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Came up happy and no more broken packages messages.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use dpkg -P instead:
sudo dpkg -P [package names...]

Some succeeded; some failed due to other packages built with those as child dependencies.

So I just read the list that dpkg spit out of the failed-due-to-depends-on,
then purged those first,
then finally purged everything.

Note, it wasn't this particular package.
However, I encountered the same issues:
apt and apt-get, frustratingly, refused to allow me to purge the packages due to being in a broken state, and it's like, Hello? I'm trying to FIX said broken state!
BUT then I tried the same thing using dpkg -P instead, and it worked!

Here's my log:

```
# man dpkg

# dpkg -P keepassxc libqt5x11extras5 libsodium23 libykpers-1-1 libyubikey0 libzxcvbn0

(Reading database ... 102160 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing keepassxc (2.3.1+dfsg.1-1) ...
Removing libqt5x11extras5:i386 (5.9.5-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libsodium23:i386 (1.0.16-2) ...
Removing libykpers-1-1:i386 (1.18.0-1) ...
Removing libyubikey0 (1.13-2) ...
Removing libzxcvbn0:i386 (2.3+dfsg-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
root@bodhi:/media/bodhi/philips2g/bodhidriverssoftware/software/keepass/XC#
root@bodhi:/media/bodhi/philips2g/bodhidriverssoftware/software/keepass/XC#
root@bodhi:/media/bodhi/philips2g/bodhidriverssoftware/software/keepass/XC#
#
#
# apt-get install keepassxc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 keepassxc : Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libsodium23 (>= 1.0.8) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libykpers-1-1 (>= 1.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libzxcvbn0 (>= 0.20150103) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtcore4 : Depends: qtcore4-l10n but it is not going to be installed
 libqtgui4 : Depends: libaudio2 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libmng2 (>= 1.0.10) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: qt-at-spi but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@bodhi:/media/bodhi/philips2g/bodhidriverssoftware/software/keepass/XC#
#
#
# dpkg -P libqtcore4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libqtcore4:i386:
 keepassx depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0).
 libqtgui4:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is to be removed.

dpkg: error processing package libqtcore4:i386 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqtcore4:i386

#
#
# dpkg -P keepassx
(Reading database ... 101804 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing keepassx (2.0.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...

#
#
# dpkg -P libqtcore4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libqtcore4:i386:
 libqtgui4:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is to be removed.

dpkg: error processing package libqtcore4:i386 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqtcore4:i386

#
# dpkg -P libqtgui4
(Reading database ... 101607 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libqtgui4:i386 (4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
root@bodhi:/media/bodhi/philips2g/bodhidriverssoftware/software/elaptopcheck# dpkg -P libqtcore4
(Reading database ... 101587 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libqtcore4:i386 (4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) ...
Purging configuration files for libqtcore4:i386 (4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...

#
#
# @@@@@
# (testing if fixed yet...?)
# @@@@@
#
#
# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 342 not upgraded.
```

FIXED!!!
(finally)

!!!!!
:D
^_^

.

.

.

.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reenable the mediabuntu repository which was disabled on your upgrade. At least that worked for me. Find the file that refers to mediabuntu in /etc/apt/sources.list.d, edit it (root), and take the # signs off the starts of the lines. Then update your repositories and do an upgrade. Problem solved for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I tried to search for mediaubuntu but didn't find anything so I just decided to remove the broken packages with (unfornately) one dependency package along which was useful to me (zsnes, a SNES gaming console emulator) and it worked.
Then, I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` and it got rid of all the weird i386 packages that had been installed, making some disk space. Everything works fine now!

Thanks anyway!